# Running Angular2 with Expressjs, different ports?

Tags: express, angular

I am using Expressjs as backend to my Angular2 application. Both projects is in the same directory structure:

```
/index.html <-- Angular index file
/app.js     <-- Expressjs
/package.json
/Gruntfile.js
/bin        <-- Expressjs bin
/routes
/public     <-- Angular directory
    /bin    <-- Angular bin
    /main.ts
    /app.component.ts
...
```

In my package.json i have this script which starts both Angular2 and Expressjs

```
   "start": "grunt & node ./bin/www & concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

This will start both as expected, but on different ports. I am wondering if this is the best solution. In some cases I would like to access /users/:id on Expressjs (when making calls from Angular) and in some cases I would like to access /users/:id on Angular, for the regular user.

Should I run Express and Angular on different ports or is there a better way to do this, ie having all Express routes in /api for instance? In that case, how do I set up that? Using different ports is just what is done as default.

Answer (score 0):

In dev mode I think you must stick to having different ports for your angular and expressJS app.
But in production, you can build you angular app (this create a dist folder) and put it as static files in expressJS.

```
app.use('/', express.static('dist'));
```

> some cases I would like to access /users/:id on Expressjs (when making calls from Angular) and in some cases I would like to access /users/:id on Angular, for the regular user.

Angular is client side and has it's proper routing system, so unless you make calls with HttpClient, you don't use the API uri.
But in reverse, if a client type a URL in his browser trying to retreive a page of Angular APP, he will instead reach the API.
So the best practice should be separating your API and your Angular paths like :

- Angular : start with '/' (/users/:id)
- API : starts with '/api/' (/api/users/:id)

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,angular project will run in the different port
Express is  node js framework  that also run in a different port